# How to extract duration time of online videos listed in a text file

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, text-files, duration

I need to check the duration of thousand of videos online. I m trying to get this from a text file containing the urls of the videos.

I have those two commands that are working great with one url, but i don't find out how to get it work with a list within a file text.

```
fmpeg -i My.url 2>&1 | grep "Duration"| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//
```

or this:

```
ffmpeg -i my.url 2>&1 | grep Duration | sed 's/Duration: \(.*\), start/\1/g'
```

im trying:

```
fmpeg -i listurls.txt 2>&1 | grep "Duration"| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//
```

or this:

```
ffmpeg -i listurls.txt 2>&1 | grep Duration | sed 's/Duration: \(.*\), start/\1/g'
```

my file text is like this:

myurl1.m3u8
myurl2.m3u8
myurl3.m3u8
myurl4.m3u8
myurl5.m3u8

I've also tried:

file 'myurl1.m3u8'
file 'myurl2.m3u8'
file 'myurl3.m3u8'
file 'myurl4.m3u8'
file 'myurl5.m3u8'

but it doesn't work.

Also some videos might not be online anymore, but still referenced, so it would give no result, but I would like if possible to have the result "0" than nothing, it will be much easier to use the results afterwards.

(awk, sed, mediainfo, exiftool, any will be good, ) Thanks in advance.

Comment: With ffmpeg, `concat` muxer present all these files as one entity, so it won't work.  Use a for loop in whatever script you're running this command in to repeat your one-url command for each url

Comment: I've edit my list now having the good format as my text file.

Comment: I've tried a script but Im not used to it, maybe you can help me to write it.   #!/bin/bash
filename="/myUrlList.txt"
n=1
while read line; do
ffmpeg -i 2>&1 | grep Duration | sed 's/Duration: \(.*\), start/\1/g'
n=$((n+1))
done < $filename

Answer (score 0):

`mediainfo` can read URLs and local files and has an option to output the duration in milliseconds. For example:

```
mediainfo --Inform='Video;%Duration%' video-path
```

On success, it outputs a number; on failure it doesn't.

Note that to read duration of a file, you probably have to download the entirety of the file.

---

The shell can convert milliseconds to seconds:

```
$ duration=91445
$ echo $((duration/1000))
91
```

Conveniently, an empty variable is treated as having value zero:

```
$ duration=''
$ echo $((duration/1000))
0
```

Note that the shell works with integers (fractional parts are discarded).

---

`.m3u8` files are lists of paths, interspersed with comments (`#...`). This can be filtered to just the paths:

```
grep -hv '^#' *.m3u8
```

It might be necessary to strip `\r` from DOS format lines:

```
... | tr -s `\r` '\n'
```

And blanks lines should be excluded:

```
... | grep '[^[:space:]]'
```

---

`xargs` or a simple while loop can combine all this:

```
grep -hv '^#' *.m3u8 |
grep '[^[:space:]]' |
tr -s '\r' '\n' |
while read -r path; do
   duration=$(
      mediainfo --Inform='Video;%Duration%' "$path" 2>&-
   )
   echo "$((duration/1000))  $path"
done
```

Comment: This code does not handle nesting (ie. if `1.m3u8` contains `2.m3u8`, then contents of `2.m3u8` will probably be ignored)

Comment: Per [M3U format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U), it may be that your files already contain duration metadata as `#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:`

Comment: mediainfo fail, it gives me error, "not found' "404" etc... but the same link works with fmpeg -i My.url 2>&1 | grep "Duration"| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//
or this:

ffmpeg -i my.url 2>&1 | grep Duration | sed 's/Duration: \(.*\), start/\1/g'

Comment: My list doesn't contain any other info or #, its not an itpv list. Its a list made by myself, containing all the videos that the site don't show the duration. Its a paying site, though i can't give the links to the videos, that contains my credentials.

Comment: You give other ways, but my question is how to get it from a list in a text file. replacing "$path" with "$myUrlList.txt" ? But mediainfo doesn't work for me with a single link anyway, so for now im just keeping trying to get it work with ffmpeg. Can someone help me with the while loop for ffmpeg?

Comment: links are like that: https://****.****.******.fr/****/vod/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3Nkbi1nbG9iYWwtc3RyZWFtaW5nLWNhY2hlLjNxc2RuLmNvbS8*******pbGVzLzIyLzA3LzI0LzYwMjY1NDUvOTM3OC1KbU13eHRWa040THljZHEtZHJtLWFlcy5pc*******aWZlc3QubTN1OCIsImlhdCI6MTY2MDcyOTU0MCwiZXhwIjoxNjYxMzM0MzQwfQ.FTgP9sNDzTu1F8idNiS0VCdPSaYxB4v7326k_vXhV5g/m.m3u8